# Store data in an application

Tags: java, database, persistence, jlist

I have an application which stores information in a `JList`. However, of course, when the application is closed all of the information is deleted from memory.

I'm trying to build the app so that when re-launched, it will contain the same data. So is there a way to store this data in a database or similar and if so? Where and how do I go about this?

Comment: *"is there a way to store this data..?"* Yes, many. *"Where and how do I go about this?"* The details of the best way depend on how much data, what form it takes, whether the app. is sand-boxed, whether it is an applet, how it is launched..

Comment: the OP has not required a database - yet, there are answers that offer the use of a DB as if it something as simple as a file.

Comment: And I find it hard to imagine a standard application which uses `JList` and a DB _on the same side - i.e. the client_

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to persist IMHO is in a File.

Try using [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) if you need a key-value map.
Or, if it you're binding more complex objects I recommend a [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) XML serialization package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your application to a database using `JDBC`. JDBC stands for Java Database Connectivity. As you can see from the name, it lets you to connect to a database. Hence, you can link your application to a database,and store your data persistenly.Here's a [link](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/) to start off with. And [here is something](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not complex and is not large (more than a few instances of a few objects) you could persist the list to a file using serialization. [This](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=398) will get you started. If you list is large or complex you might consider a database. Searching for JDBC will in your favorite search engine will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a plain flat file.  It's simple; you can have one going in no time.  (The learning curve is much less than with databases.)  And it's fast; you can read a 1 GB file before you can even log on to a DB.  Java serialization is a bit tricky, but it can be a very powerful way to save vast amounts of complicated data.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743767/796401) for things to watch out for, plus more helpful links.)  If, for instance, you wanted to save a large, complex game between sessions, serializing it is the way to go.  No need to convert an Object Oriented structure to a relational one.

**Use a database:**
if you want to *add* data to a large file, or read only *part* of the data from a large file.  Or if other processes are going to read and modify it.

**Consider a DB:**
if you are already using one for other purposes.  If the user might start on another machine and have trouble finding the file from the last session and the data is not too extensive.  Or if the data is relational in nature anyway and someone else may be interested in looking at it.

So if you have a simple case where the user always starts in the same directory, just write and read a simple file.  If you have a lot of complex, extensive OO data, use a flat file even if it is *not* easy to do--you'll need the speed.  Otherwise, think about a DB.